# How can i determine left right up and down shake gesture in ios?

Tags: ios, accelerometer

I want to determine shake gesture along with the direction in which device is shacked like left right up or down. I am using

`-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration` method

but i am not getting the direction of shake from this method. 
Can anyone suggest any algorithm or something through which it is possible to detect.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need the Core Motion framework for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223296/how-to-detect-direction-of-shake-in-iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253058/horizontal-and-verticle-shake-count-using-accelerometer-in-iphone-ipad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018770/how-to-determine-the-direction-of-a-iphone-shake

Comment: @Vincent  am able to detect right and left movement but not up and down and also its difficult to detect when both up and right motion takes place.

Comment: For left and right, I posted my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29030985/1668837

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorials used for u

[https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-morrison/ios-getting-started-accelerometer-data](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-morrison/ios-getting-started-accelerometer-data)
http://wwwbruegge.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/home/98-teaching/tutorials/505-sgd-ws13-tutorial-core-motion
[https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-9/the-core-motion-framework](http://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-9/the-core-motion-framework)